# ¿Como acomodar insertar datos en cada posición de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy trabajando con dos arrays, uno de ellos contiene 3 arrays en su interior con sus respectivos datos y el otro solo contiene cadenas de texto. Necesito acomodar cada datos de los arrays internos con cada texto del array individual.

```
var jDatos = [[17.28, 22.58, 27.91, 31.95, 36.32, 41.73, 45.78, 48.55, 53.48, 47.82],[11.83, 20.23, 26.9, 32.39, 36.95, 41.48, 46.41, 48.82, 52.58, 49.42],[14.2, 20.94, 27.36, 32.12, 36.33, 41.4, 46.58, 48.8, 52.69, 48.9]]; //Array general de datos

var jLabels = ["0 mts", "1 mts", "2 mts", "3 mts", "4 mts", "5 mts", "6 mts", "7 mts", "8 mts", "9 mts"]; //Array de texto
```

Lo que quiero obtener es un arreglo general, pero en este los datos deben tener este formato {y: "0 mts", x: 17.28} a modo de coordenadas. Lo que he hecho hasta ahora es acomodarlos de esta manera, pero tengo problemas al separar cada conjunto de datos como en el `arrDatos`

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jDatos.length; i++){ //Recorrido de jDatos
  for(var j = 0; j < jLabels.length; j++){ //Recorrido de jLabels       
    cAux = {y: jLabels[j], x: jDatos[i][j]} //Acomodo de datos en formato coordenadas
    coordenadas.push(cAux); //Insercion de cada par de coordenadas en arreglo general
  }
}
```

Funciona bien al acomodar correctamente los datos, pero lo que obtengo es un arreglo general con todos los datos.

```
0: {y: "0 mts", x: 17.28}
1: {y: "1 mts", x: 22.58}
2: {y: "2 mts", x: 27.91}
3: {y: "3 mts", x: 31.95}
4: {y: "4 mts", x: 36.32}
5: {y: "5 mts", x: 41.73}
6: {y: "6 mts", x: 45.78}
7: {y: "7 mts", x: 48.55}
8: {y: "8 mts", x: 53.48}
9: {y: "9 mts", x: 47.82}
10: {y: "0 mts", x: 11.83}
11: {y: "1 mts", x: 20.23}
12: {y: "2 mts", x: 26.9}
13: {y: "3 mts", x: 32.39}
14: {y: "4 mts", x: 36.95}
15: {y: "5 mts", x: 41.48}
16: {y: "6 mts", x: 46.41}
17: {y: "7 mts", x: 48.82}
18: {y: "8 mts", x: 52.58}
19: {y: "9 mts", x: 49.42}
20: {y: "0 mts", x: 14.2}
21: {y: "1 mts", x: 20.94}
22: {y: "2 mts", x: 27.36}
23: {y: "3 mts", x: 32.12}
24: {y: "4 mts", x: 36.33}
25: {y: "5 mts", x: 41.4}
26: {y: "6 mts", x: 46.58}
27: {y: "7 mts", x: 48.8}
28: {y: "8 mts", x: 52.69}
29: {y: "9 mts", x: 48.9}
```

Lo que yo quiero obtener es lo siguiente

```
[

[
    {y: "0 mts", x: 17.28}
    {y: "1 mts", x: 22.58}
    {y: "2 mts", x: 27.91}
    {y: "3 mts", x: 31.95}
    {y: "4 mts", x: 36.32}
    {y: "5 mts", x: 41.73}
    {y: "6 mts", x: 45.78}
    {y: "7 mts", x: 48.55}
    {y: "8 mts", x: 53.48}
    {y: "9 mts", x: 47.82}
  ],
  [
    {y: "0 mts", x: 11.83}
    {y: "1 mts", x: 20.23}
    {y: "2 mts", x: 26.9}
    {y: "3 mts", x: 32.39}
    {y: "4 mts", x: 36.95}
    {y: "5 mts", x: 41.48}
    {y: "6 mts", x: 46.41}
    {y: "7 mts", x: 48.82}
    {y: "8 mts", x: 52.58}
    {y: "9 mts", x: 49.42}
  ],
  [  
    {y: "0 mts", x: 14.2}
    {y: "1 mts", x: 20.94}
    {y: "2 mts", x: 27.36}
    {y: "3 mts", x: 32.12}
    {y: "4 mts", x: 36.33}
    {y: "5 mts", x: 41.4}
    {y: "6 mts", x: 46.58}
    {y: "7 mts", x: 48.8}
    {y: "8 mts", x: 52.69}
    {y: "9 mts", x: 48.9}
  ]  
]
```

Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para obtener los resultados asi debes meterlos en cAux de 10 en 10, luego ese cAux incluirlo en coordenadas, y luego volver cAux = [] para meter los siguientes 10:

```
var coordenadas = [];
var cAux = [];

for(var i = 0; i < jDatos.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < jLabels.length; j++){
        cAux.push({y:jLabels[j], x:jDatos[i][j]});
    }

    coordenadas.push(cAux);
    cAux = [];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Casi lo tienes, te faltó un pequeño detalle. Fíjate que a la variable *coordenadas* le estas asignando cada uno de los elementos que creas en el bucle. Para que funcione como quieres, debes agrupar cada uno de estos elementos en un array auxiliar y posteriormente añadirlo al array *coordenadas*. Se ve mejor con un ejemplo.

```js
var jDatos = [[17.28, 22.58, 27.91, 31.95, 36.32, 41.73, 45.78, 48.55, 53.48, 47.82],[11.83, 20.23, 26.9, 32.39, 36.95, 41.48, 46.41, 48.82, 52.58, 49.42],[14.2, 20.94, 27.36, 32.12, 36.33, 41.4, 46.58, 48.8, 52.69, 48.9]]; //Array general de datos

var jLabels = ["0 mts", "1 mts", "2 mts", "3 mts", "4 mts", "5 mts", "6 mts", "7 mts", "8 mts", "9 mts"]; //Array de texto

// Se inicializan como array
var coordenadas = [],
   cAux = [];
    
for(var i = 0; i < jDatos.length; i++){ //Recorrido de jDatos
  for(var j = 0; j < jLabels.length; j++){ //Recorrido de jLabels       
  
    // Se añade el nuevo elemento al array auxiliar
    cAux.push({y: jLabels[j], x: jDatos[i][j]}); 

  }
  
  // Se añade el array auxiliar a coordenadas y se limpia
  coordenadas.push(cAux);
  cAux = [];
}

console.log(coordenadas);
```

Comment: Perfecto es lo que necesitaba, les agradezco a los dos. No tengo mucha experiencia en javascript. En PHP estaba acostumbrado a usar algo como `coordenadas[i][j] = cAux`y quedaba, pero en este lenguaje cambian algunas cosas.